# CanCan check_authorization not throwing AccessDenied Exception for Non RESTful Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

**Motivation**

I'm trying to use CanCan in an application where one of the controllers isn't associated with a resource - non RESTful controller. I want actions for that controller to be authorized conditionally dependant on other resources and session parameters.

**Background**

[The CanCanCan documentation for Non RESTful controllers](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers) states that

> you should not use the load_and_authorize_resource method since there
>   is no resource to load. Instead you can call authorize! in each action
>   separately.

Which shouldn't be an issue anyway as in theory I should be locking it down and ensuring that authorization happens on every action in my application by adding `check_authorization` to my `ApplicationController`. According to [the CanCanCan documentation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan):

> This will raise an exception if authorization is **not** performed in an
>   action.

**Problem**

The issue I'm having is that check_authorization doesn't appear to be locking down the actions for non RESTful controllers. Actions that don't declare authorize! are being executed without raising any AccessDenied exceptions.

Below is an MCVE that represents what I am doing. Am I doing something wrong or have I discovered a bug? What is the 'right' way to do this?

**Implementation**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  check_authorization

  def current_user
    Object.new
  end

  protected

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    puts "CanCan::AccessDenied Exception thrown : message=#{exception.message}"
  end
end
```

Within my controller I'm trying to manually authorize but only if certain conditions are met:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def new
    authorize! :foo, :bar, unless: true
    puts 'FooController#new'
  end

  def index
    authorize! :foo, :bar, if: true
    puts 'FooController#index'
  end

  def show
    puts 'FooController#show'
  end
end
```

And the Ability class that enables the :foo :bar authorization:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    puts 'CanCan::Ability#initialise'
    can :foo, :bar
  end
end
```

Output generated in Rails console:

```
2.3.0 :001 > app.get '/foo/new'
CanCan::Ability#initialise
FooController#new

2.3.0 :002 > app.get '/foo'
CanCan::Ability#initialise
FooController#index

2.3.0 :001 > app.get '/foo/1'
FooController#show
```

Note, that the `show` action doesn't even have the `authorize!` declaration, yet still allows execution without throwing an exception.

Also, what I don't understand is that `Ability#initialize` isn't called at all for the `show` action. To add to my confusion - the `Ability#initialize` method is called for both `new` and `index` - you would expect one of them to have the same behaviour as the `show` action, given that the `new` action shouldn't be invoking the `authorize!` method.

Answer (score 1):

A smoother way to do it would be defining `check_authorization` in your `ApplicationController`, something like this:

```
def check_authorization
  raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new('Some message', params[:action].to_sym, params[:controller].to_sym) if cannot? params[:action].to_sym, params[:controller].to_sym
end
```

Your `rescue_from` block would then do the rest.

And inside your controllers where you need to check authorization, rather than calling `authorize!` in the beginning of each action, you could actually prefer doing something like :

```
before_action: check_authorization
```

in the beginning, or using `before_action` with `except` or `only`, if you need to check authorization over selective actions, something like:

```
before_action: check_authorization, except: [:create, :update]
```

or

```
before_action: check_authorization, only: [:show, :update_permissions]
```

I don't know if it solves your problems completely, but it sure is a more readable way and works for both RESTful and non-RESTful controllers. Give it a try.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but how could this work? You suggest that rather than authorize! I call `before_action :check_authorization` which will then raise a `CanCan::AccessDenied` exception ... making it impossible for me to authorize the action.

Comment: There is an `if` at the end of `raise` line. List all the permissions you require, inside `ability.rb`, using either `can` or `cannot` and then, when an action is called that has `check_authorization` as a precursor, it will raise `AccessDenied` if the permission does not exist in `ability.rb`, else it will progress just fine. Also i just noticed you calling the same pair of `action` and 'class' over `authorize!` in all your actions. Shouldn't it be different for different actions? Also `action` is the 1st part and `class` the 2nd for all `authorize!`. `CanCan` docs explain all this clearly.

Comment: Ah I understand fully now what you are doing, thank you for the clear explanation. Unfortunately I don't think I can use the abilities in that way because I'm not using resources. For RESTful actions you are able to provide some scope for the ability which effectively makes the authorization conditional - e.g. `can :read, Product, organisation_id: @user.organisation_id`. This is why I am authorizing conditionally within the action itself - I may have oversimplified my MCVE and not made this clear enough. Your input has merit though and provided a bit more clarity so I shall upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to this issue.

In the scenario where, because of the conditional statements, you want the authorisation to fail within an action you need to explicitly `authorize!` an ability that you know won't be defined. For example;

```
condition ? (authorize! :foo, :bar) : (authorize! nil, nil)
```

This will then result in the `AccessDenied` exception being thrown for a non RESTful controller when the `condition` is false, which you can then handle as you would for other RESTful controllers where a resource hasn't been authorised.

However, this solution is not ideal - it feels very hacky and just doesn't feel like the CanCan way of doing things.